# get time in days from random date in Go

Tags: datetime, go

I have an API endpoint which will gather some structured data and one of the fields is a time stamp with this format:

`"2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"`

My requirement is to caculate the number of days since this timestamp style.

I have this code which is working but I am looking for improvements [goplayground](https://go.dev/play/p/-WZasVsbm8b):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    s1 := "2023-01-20"
    date1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", s1)
    t1 := time.Now().Round(0)
    days := int(math.Ceil(t1.Sub(date1).Hours() / 24))
    fmt.Println("days: ", days)
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I was not able to find anything in time.Time that recogizes that time format, so I have done string parsing instead, to get just the date (parsing at first white space), which I will insert into the `s1` as a variable.  That is fine (code not listed here) but I would prefer if time.Time could parse just the date, from that format (`"2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"`).
2. Is there a better way to calculate the days since the timestamp, perhaps without having to import the math package?  I was somewhat suprised at how difficult this seemed to be because I thought time.Since() would be able to do this, but I was not successful with that, so I came up with this code.

Comment: Perhaps something like (t1.unix-t2.unix)/60/60/24: https://go.dev/play/p/_7UvTp2uLcd

Comment: Use the `"2006-01-02 15:04:05"` layout to parse your timestamps. You can "mimic" `math.Ceil()` with integer arithmetic, but seriously, what do you have against importing `math` from the standard lib?

Comment: @icza yes fair point, nothing against importing math pkg if that is the best way to do this. Was just somewhat suprised that I wasnt finding a more straight-forward way in time.Time to do this.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what `time.Time.Round(0)` is supposed to produce?

Comment: @kostix: "The canonical way to strip a monotonic clock reading is to use t = t.Round(0)." https://pkg.go.dev/time@latest

Comment: Ah, thanks. I would assume that the result of `time.Parse()` does not contain the monitonic clock part, and hence `time.Sub` would not use it anyway in the code example being discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following with `time.Since()` that works, as I think, as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // this is the input from JSON
    // used this as an example for checking calculation in Go playground
    // which starts time at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC
    timeStr := "2009-11-11 23:00:00.000000"

    parseLayout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"

    t, err := time.Parse(parseLayout, timeStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error parsing datetime value %v: %w", timeStr, err)
    }

    durationDays := int(time.Since(t).Abs().Hours() / 24)
    fmt.Println(durationDays)
}
```

When you use the format string posted by Matteo your time string should be parsed correctly. See https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants for format string details.

Comment: With int, this code depends on the time of day of source. For example if NOW is 2023-01-25 17:00:00 (UTC) and check time is 2023-01-24 10:00:00 (UTC) then it would return 1 day. If check time is 2023-01-24 18:00:00 then it would return 0. But the result should be 1 in either case. BTW, time.Since() is a shortcut to t.Sub(t2) but it uses time.Now without truncating it.

Comment: I think not having to import the math package + the better parsing technique (no separate strings op) makes this work for me. @CetinBasoz I will have to study your example case and make sure I'm not impacted by it, but for my use case I don't think that will impact, but I appreciate you pointing that out as something to be aware of.

Comment: @RobertCampbell, yes it would work if you are ok with 1 day error. If you need exact result, check my reply.

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't have date\datetime data type and you would parse from string.

```
json := "2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"
t := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999", json)
```

You don't need the Math package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    s1 := "2023-01-20" // or "2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"
    date1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", s1)
    t1 := time.Now()

    // Unfortunately there isn't a direct truncation to Date only
    y, m, d := t1.Date()
    t1 = time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    // now is truncated to Date

    days := t1.Sub(date1).Hours() / 24
    fmt.Println("days: ", days)
}
```

EDIT: Extending to your JSON case, you would need truncation to date a lot. You could do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type myTime time.Time

func main() {

    s1 := "2023-01-20 09:05:27.567995" // or "2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"
    date1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999", s1)
    date1 = myTime(date1).DateOnly()
    t1 := myTime(time.Now()).DateOnly()

    days := t1.Sub(date1).Hours() / 24
    fmt.Println("days: ", days)

}

func (t myTime) DateOnly() time.Time {
    y, m, d := time.Time(t).Date()
    return time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first point of your question, you could parse using the pattern `2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999` like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    x := "2022-08-30 09:05:27.567995"

    fmt.Println(time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999", x))
}
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/v4TSXJyNOxg